# How To Run A Macro At Same Time Across Multiple Workbook Files?

Tags: excel, vba

For the first time thanks for this macro! I have a little problem. I need 'resave' many workbooks with many worksheets as values. I used this code :

But this code 'resave' only first workbook and other only opened. Where is the problem?

Thanks for your help

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim xFd As FileDialog
Dim xFdItem As Variant
Dim xFileName As String
Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If xFd.Show = -1 Then
xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
Do While xFileName <> ""
With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)

Dim wsh As Worksheet
For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
wsh.Cells.Copy
wsh.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
xFileName = Dir
Loop
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
    Sub OpenFiles()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
Dim wsh As Worksheet

MyFolder = "Enter Folder directory here"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsm")

Do While MyFile <> ""
Set wbCurrent = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False)
For Each wsh In wbCurrent.Worksheets
        wsh.Cells.Copy
        wsh.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next


wbCurrent.Close SaveChanges:=True
MyFile = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

If all your workbooks are in the same folder, this will open each one, copy and paste the cells in each worksheet, then Save, before moving onto the next workbook.

Answer (score 0):

`ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook with the macro in it. If you want to refer to other workbooks you need to define variables for them. Run this simple macro when several workbooks are open to get the idea, and then adjust to your needs.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim wk As Workbook
For Each wk In Workbooks
    MsgBox "this workbook is named: " & wk.Name
Next
End Sub
```